# Rails 'to_sql' without '\'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I just wanted to display

```
Shop.all.to_sql
```

as

```
 => "SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops""
```

but got

```
 => "SELECT \"shops\".* FROM \"shops\""
```

I tried gsub, but rails ignores '\'

```
Shop.all.to_sql.gsub('\', '')
```

How could I get rid of '\'?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Those `\` are not really there - this is way ruby displays strings (or rather this is the way `inspect` method works for strings). In short, it is to say that the next `"` is not the end of the string but rather a part of it:

```
'"'    #=> "\""
```

To see there are no slashes, tell ruby to display the resulting strings:

```
puts Shop.all.to_sql
# SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops"
#=> nil
```

Comment: in short, prefix the `to_sql` with `puts`

Answer (score -2):

first parameter to gsub should be a regexp. Also, there are no backslashes in that string, there are double quotes, so `Shop.all.to_sql.gsub(/"/, '\'')` should work